# Work Done by a time-variable Force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

My problem gives a time-dependent force as follows:

lets say that the force is fairly simple, $F=6t$

lets say that we want to find the work done in the 1st second.

Here's my approach:

$W=F(t).v$

So, for a small interval where force can be considered constant,

$dW=F.dv$

[image: consult this]

using the kinematical relations:

$v+dv=v+(6t/m)*dt$

$dv=6tdt$ 
(for m=1kg)

therefore,

$=>dw=6t*6tdt$

$=>dw=36t^2dt$

so we can integrate using any limits on time I guess? But in my case, this doesn't work (wrong answer) idk why, it seems correct to me lol

For anyone who wants the answer, its 
$4.5J$ 
(at least according to my textbook)

Comment: find the area of the triangle of base length 1 and height 6. this is the change in momentum in the first second; which is also the total momentum of the particle since you state it starts at rest. Then multiply by $\frac{1}{m}$ for the velocity and compute the kinetic energy,  $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ which will equal Work done. there’s no need for integral calculus.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing work and power.

Because of the pioneering work (no pun intended !!!) of James Watt, the unit of **power** is called the Watt and denoted by $W$. This should not be considered as the first letter of "work" in the physical meaning of the word. I think this may be the cause of your confusion.

You are supposed to compute the **work**.

Work is the integral in time of power.

Answer (score 3):

## Wrong units

> lets say that the force is fairly simple, $F=6t$

And that's your first problem, right here. You *cannot* disregard units and expect to get any correct or even well-defined result from your calculations.

The left-hand side is a force (in Newton), the right-hand side is a duration (in seconds). This cannot work, and you cannot use this equation anywhere.

You should replace it with $F = \frac{6\mathrm{N}}{\mathrm{s}} * t$

## Back to basics

- Time $t$ is in seconds.
- Force $F$ is in Newtons.
- Work is in Joules.
- Power is in Watts.
- Force * velocity is in Watts.
- Force * distance is in Joules.

Comment: Thats what i Thought, but the problem says just that. No extra info regarding the force itself. here's the problem if you want "A time-dependent force f=6t acts on a particle of mass 1kg. If the particle starts from rest, the work done by the force in the 1st second is...."

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}a &=\dfrac{F}{m} = \dfrac{6}{m}t \\ v(t)-v(0) &= \int\limits_0^t a~dt=?\end{align}$$

Using velocity you can find the kinetic energy(which is work done here if $v(0)=0$). See if you can finish it off..

Comment: Beware ! Your answer is of course correct, but you are giving the entire answer to what is essentially a "homework and exercise" question. I have previously been censured by the "people in the know" for doing just that. We are only supposed to give hints, not solve the problem.

Comment: Even a partial solution can be called "almost solution" if it gets too close.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll remove some... just so you know I'm not so good with physics haha. Your method looks nice but I'm still wondering how to convert $F.dr$  to $P.dt$

Comment: Easy enough but this is not the place to tell you. I'll try to open a discussion.

Comment: That would be awesome.. how do I open discussion? I don't see chat option on my end

Comment: Nor do I. I asked the question on Meta

Comment: One way might be to force the system to offer the box by putting too many comments...

Comment: Which looks as a rather stupid way, but  I don't see any clever one...

Comment: Yeah it then shows

Comment: a popup to continue in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101674/discussion-between-pooja-and-alfred).

Answer (score 1):

$F = 6t \implies a = \frac{dv}{dt} = 6t/m = 6t$

$\implies v = 3t^{2}$

$\implies dx = 3t^{2}dt$  as  $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$

$W = \int Fdx = \int 6t\cdot 3t^{2} dt = \frac{9}{2}t^{4}$

Therefore, at $t = 1s, W = 4.5 J$